# Take register detail down to other div

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a table with a check option column for each register. What I want to do is when one of the checks is available and press button "modify" It will appear the detail of the selected register in a new div.

Show and hide detail when button is pressed no problem. Fill the detail with the selected row is the problem.

how would you do it?

thanks all.

Comment: Exactly, we'd like to have your code. Besides we're interested to know if you would have always max 1 detailDIV, or, since you use checkboxes, more detailDivs. We don't know if you have generated row-ID's or so.. Plz show HTML + JS.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so hard anyways.

[CodePen.IO example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lkbuw)

```
function rowToDiv() {

    var row = document.getElementById("row1"),
        html = [];

    for( var i = 0, cells = row.children, ln = cells.length; i < ln; i++ ) {

        html.push( cells[ i ].innerText + " " );
    }

    alert( html.join('') );
}
```